# Pass dropdown options to PHP variable (without page refresh)

Tags: php, ajax, post, input

I'm trying to pass the value of the dropdown menu to the PHP variable `$anno`, so the `print_r()` function at the end can use the realtive `$coefficiente` variable (which depends on `$anno`).

```
<select name="anno">
<option>1940</option>
<option>1941</option>
<option>1942</option>
</select>

<?php

$importo = "100";
$anno = $_POST["anno"];

if ( $anno == "1940" ) { $coefficiente = "10"; } ;
if ( $anno == "1941" ) { $coefficiente = "20"; } ;
if ( $anno == "1942" ) { $coefficiente = "30"; } ;

print_r(($importo*$coefficiente)/1936.27); echo '€';

?>
```

Can this be "AJAXified"?

At this time when I choose the dropdown option, the `print_r` function isn't updated. Do I need a submit button?

Comment: Sure you can, you just need a handler for the onChange event on the dropdown (you ll put your ajax request there)

Comment: I tried with this jQuery function but can't notice any difference.. :D
http://pastebin.com/ecuvnNaP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to calculate your formula in the same page, don't use PHP use Javascript**

```
<select name="anno">
  <option>1940</option>
  <option>1941</option>
  <option>1942</option>
</select>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // We bind our AJAX handler to the onChange event of the select element
    $("select[name='anno']").on('change', function(e) {
      var importo = "100";
      var anno = $(this).val();
      var coef = "";
      if (anno == 1940) { coef = 10; }
      if (anno == 1941) { coef = 20; }
      if (anno == 1942) { coef = 30; }

      alert(importo*coef/1936.27 + "€");
    })
});
```

**For PHP handling, use AJAX** (warning I couldn't test this!)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
    // We bind our AJAX handler to the onChange event of the select element
    $("select[name='anno']").on('change', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "your_php_script.php",
                data: { anno: $(this).val() },
            })
              .done(function(data) {
                alert(data); 
              })
              .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Something went wrong!\n" + errorThrown);
              });
    })
});
```

Comment: What should I put in `url :` if the script is on the same page?

Comment: It shouldn't be on the same page, should it? If it *must* be on the same page, just put the name of the php script (if your page is called *page.php* just put page.php). But I strongly advice you to put it on another script (or page as you call it). If its is on the same your PHP code will be executed even when the user has not make any selection yet... (you can change that putting an ```if (isset($_POST['anno'])``` before your PHP code but IMHO this is *ugly* :-)

Comment: Oh, if you want to be on the same page, then you could do everything in JS, see edited answer